# Monte Carlo dropout doesn't change anything with any rate

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

i used to try normal dropout and it always gives better result
so this time I wanted to try the Monte Carlo method to see how it works but it doesn't change anything at any rate; it all seems like before. this is my code:

```
with keras.backend.learning_phase_scope(1):
    ypr=np.stack([model.predict(xscale)
                              for sample in range(100)])
y=ypr.mean(axis=0)
```

do i miss something?
thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem. An alternative is to subclass the Dropout layer and override the call() method to force its training argument to True:

```
class MonteCarloDropout(Dropout):
    def call(self, inputs):
        return super().call(inputs, training=True)
```

Replace the Dropout layers in your model with MonteCarloDropout layers and it will work as you expect.

Comment: not completely what i expected, but i figured it out what do you mean